# Writing clean code in html

Tags: html, coding-style

I want to validate a form and show error message corresponding to a validation code.

Following is my current code

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="Ctrl.getValidationCode()=== Ctrl.VALIDATION_CODE['EXCEEDED_RANGE'] ">fromdate exceeded todate</div>
```

Is it better to use this

```
ng-show="Ctrl.getValidationCode()=== Ctrl.VALIDATION_CODE['EXCEEDED_RANGE']"
```

Or use this instead

```
ng-show="Ctrl.getValidationCode()=== 1"
```

I think the first one is better Because It's cleaner to the second one.
But the first one is too long.

Could you give me your opinions and advice?

Comment: If both are functionally equivalent, you should usually go for the understandable one. You or others might be coming back to the code and wonder what is happening, so it's always better to write understandable code. Furthermore, "too long" seems very subjective. Let me add that this question is entirely opinion-based and may thus be downvoted and closed by others.

Answer (score 1):

First one is more practical, because you can give your code some freedom. So if you use that validation code on few pages, it's lot easier to manage that code. Because if you need to change code, you will change it only on one place instead of going to separate pages. It's something like convention.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way is a new directive that handle all form erros messages in your application.